# Counting rows under multindex dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following dataframe indexed as follows:

```
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
columns_to_keep=['STATE','COUNTY','STNAME','CTYNAME']
census_df=census_df[census_df['SUMLEV']==50]
df=census_df[columns_to_keep]
df = df.set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
df.head()
```

And looks like this

[image]

Where "STNAME" is the state name and "CITYNAME" is the county name. Every state and county have a specific code as show in the columns "STATE" and "COUNTY".

I need to return the name of the state with the maximum counties. So far I have done something like this

```
df.groupby('STATE').count()
num_state= g['COUNTY'].argmax()
state_name = df[df['STATE']==num_state].index[0][0]
```

But I am sure there must be an easier way to count through rows in multindex dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: (df.reset_index().groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].count()).idxmax()?